# VS2010 Building Solution - Add Files to BIN folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, file, build, post-build-event

We have a solution comprising of a windows application and various library files. Not all of the library files are referenced by the main windows application however we would like to have all the library files included in the output build folder "bin".

Obviously one solution is to simply reference every single library from the Windows application however we would like to avoid any unnecessary referencing.

How can we include additional files into our build folder?

This is a C# project.

Comment: Are all the additional libraries .NET assemblies?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the pre-build or post-build events in the project settings to copy the additional files.

You can do this simply by doing a bunch of `copy source target`, or you could even be fancy and write an nmake file.  You do have to maintain the list of source files however...

Edit:

One other thought.  Your assumption is that this is "unnecessary referencing".  However, if your application depends on these assemblies to run, whether or not they are compile time references, then don't these dependencies become "necessary" references?  In that case, isn't adding them as references and letting Studio's build system work for you the best (and simplest) approach?

Comment: Would this be common practice?

Comment: Wait, I'm going to guess that these are run-time dependencies?  In that case, yes, its very common practice.

Comment: @Marty: Its common practice to copy runtime dependencies in your build file. We use nant and there is a copy task which supports wildcard matching so its easy to copy all assemblies/etc in a folder or its children folders.

Comment: Nader, you make an excellent point. I'd like to hear others thoughts on this. The application doesn't use some libraries but some libraries which the application needs do. So in effect, they are "cousin" references.

Comment: "Cousin" references get automatically copied over -- so this shouldn't be a problem.  Are you referring to references that aren't referred to by any other assembly (ie run time dependencies of your project, or one of its references)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have changed the Windows application to ONLY reference the libraries it requires and have changed the "Build Output" path for all the remaining libraries to the main output "bin". Now we have all the required files being built to the output location.

Comment: Ah, that's the question I forgot to ask ("Do you control all the projects that produce your references, and are all of them building a single product"), in which case, "build them all to a common output folder" is the right answer.  If that's the case, I'd actually recommend you unaccept this answer, write your own with the solution that worked for you, and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to change the build location for all "libraries" within the solution to the main output "bin" location. The main Windows application only references the libraries that it depends upon however all the libraries are built to the one "common" location.

Thanks to Nader Shirazie for help with this question.